# Extract SQL query Result as variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table having column formula and row (sum(marks)). I want to extract the row only(single record) as a variable using SQL. How can I achieve it?

```
result_variable=sum(marks)
```

Comment: Can you give some minimal, reproducible data to work with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to store the value:

```
 SET @var_name = (SELECT SUM(Marks) FROM table_name);
 SELECT @var_name;
```

... or

```
 SELECT @var_name = SUM(Marks), MIN(Marks), MAX(Marks) FROM table_name;
 SELECT @var_name;
```

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=66e276ca3a03019ac79b38942d9147a0)

Comment: I can't Directly hard code sum(marks) as it can be any record like count(students) or may be anything. Is there any way to convert the logic column record into variable. So that it can be used further.